# Why do I get an MobSF Error during setup?

Tags: android, security

installing (run.bat) MobSF I have this error during installation on a Win10. I have c++ insalled. Do you have any idea why this breaks?
[run.bat of MobSF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTyv2.png)
Thanks.

I have tried running "clean.bat", installing C++ and insstalling SDK

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.19044.2604]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\DAS>cd C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF

C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF>./setup.bat
"." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF>setup.bat
[INSTALL] Checking for Python version 3.8+
[INSTALL] Found Python 3.10.4
[INSTALL] Found pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\das\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (23.0.1)
[INSTALL] Found OpenSSL executable
[INSTALL] Found Visual Studio Build Tools
[INSTALL] Creating venv
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\das\desktop\k\pentesting android\mobile-security-framework-mobsf\venv\lib\site-packages (22.0.4)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4
    Uninstalling pip-22.0.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.4
Successfully installed pip-23.0.1
[INSTALL] Installing Requirements
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.38.4
Ignoring gunicorn: markers 'platform_system != "Windows"' don't match your environment
Collecting Django>=3.1.5
  Downloading Django-4.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 8.1/8.1 MB 12.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting lxml>=4.6.2
  Downloading lxml-4.9.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.8 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 3.8/3.8 MB 12.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting rsa>=4.7
  Downloading rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting biplist>=1.0.3
  Downloading biplist-1.0.3.tar.gz (21 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting requests>=2.25.1
  Downloading requests-2.28.2-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 62.8/62.8 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting bs4>=0.0.1
  Downloading bs4-0.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting colorlog>=4.7.2
  Downloading colorlog-6.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting macholib>=1.14
  Downloading macholib-1.16.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
Collecting whitenoise>=5.2.0
  Downloading whitenoise-6.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting waitress>=1.4.4
  Downloading waitress-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 57.7/57.7 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting psutil>=5.8.0
  Downloading psutil-5.9.4-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (252 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 252.5/252.5 kB 15.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting shelljob>=0.6.2
  Downloading shelljob-0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (9.9 kB)
Collecting asn1crypto>=1.4.0
  Downloading asn1crypto-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (105 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 105.0/105.0 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting oscrypto>=1.2.1
  Downloading oscrypto-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 194.6/194.6 kB 11.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting distro>=1.5.0
  Downloading distro-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting IP2Location==8.9.0
  Downloading IP2Location-8.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting lief>=0.12.1
  Downloading lief-0.12.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (4.9 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 4.9/4.9 MB 12.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting http-tools>=2.1.0
  Downloading http-tools-2.1.1.tar.gz (550 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 550.3/550.3 kB 17.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting libsast>=1.5.1
  Downloading libsast-1.5.2.tar.gz (36 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pdfkit>=0.6.1
  Downloading pdfkit-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting google-play-scraper>=0.1.2
  Downloading google_play_scraper-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting androguard==3.4.0a1
  Downloading androguard-3.4.0a1-py3-none-any.whl (918 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 918.1/918.1 kB 14.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting apkid==2.1.4
  Downloading apkid-2.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (116 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 116.6/116.6 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting quark-engine==22.10.1
  Downloading quark_engine-22.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 97.6/97.6 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting frida==15.2.2
  Downloading frida-15.2.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting tldextract==3.4.0
  Downloading tldextract-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 93.9/93.9 kB 5.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting openstep-parser==1.5.4
  Downloading openstep_parser-1.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting svgutils==0.3.4
  Downloading svgutils-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml==0.16.13
  Downloading ruamel.yaml-0.16.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 111.9/111.9 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting click==8.0.1
  Downloading click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 97.4/97.4 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting decorator==4.4.2
  Downloading decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting asgiref<4,>=3.5.2
  Downloading asgiref-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting tzdata; sys_platform == "win32"
  Downloading tzdata-2022.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 340.1/340.1 kB 10.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Downloading sqlparse-0.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 42.8/42.8 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.3
  Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 77.1/77.1 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 140.6/140.6 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-3.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 96.5/96.5 kB 5.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2022.12.7-py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 155.3/155.3 kB 9.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 61.5/61.5 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (129 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 129.4/129.4 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting colorama; sys_platform == "win32"
  Downloading colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting altgraph>=0.17
  Downloading altgraph-0.17.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting mitmproxy==6.0.2
  Downloading mitmproxy-6.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.1/1.1 MB 14.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting markupsafe==2.0.1
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (15 kB)
Collecting pyyaml>=6.0
  Downloading PyYAML-6.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (151 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 151.7/151.7 kB 8.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting networkx>=2.2
  Downloading networkx-3.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.0 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 2.0/2.0 MB 13.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting matplotlib>=3.0.2
  Downloading matplotlib-3.7.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (7.6 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 7.6/7.6 MB 12.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pygments>=2.3.1
  Downloading Pygments-2.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.1/1.1 MB 11.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pydot>=1.4.1
  Downloading pydot-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting ipython>=5.0.0
  Downloading ipython-8.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (784 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 784.3/784.3 kB 12.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting yara-python-dex>=1.0.1
  Downloading yara_python_dex-1.0.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (130 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 130.2/130.2 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting kaleido
  Downloading kaleido-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (65.9 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 65.9/65.9 MB 12.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting prettytable>=1.0.0
  Downloading prettytable-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting tqdm
  Downloading tqdm-4.64.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 78.5/78.5 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting plotly
  Downloading plotly-5.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15.2 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 15.2/15.2 MB 12.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.19
  Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.19-py3-none-any.whl (368 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 368.4/368.4 kB 23.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.5.3-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (10.4 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 10.4/10.4 MB 12.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting rzpipe
  Downloading rzpipe-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting graphviz
  Downloading graphviz-0.20.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 47.0/47.0 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\das\desktop\k\pentesting android\mobile-security-framework-mobsf\venv\lib\site-packages (from frida==15.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 26)) (58.1.0)
Collecting requests-file>=1.4
  Downloading requests_file-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
Collecting filelock>=3.0.8
  Downloading filelock-3.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
Collecting soupsieve>1.2
  Downloading soupsieve-2.4-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting tornado<7,>=4.3
  Downloading tornado-6.2-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (425 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 425.3/425.3 kB 13.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pyparsing<2.5,>=2.4.2
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 67.8/67.8 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting passlib<1.8,>=1.6.5
  Downloading passlib-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (525 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 525.6/525.6 kB 16.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting pydivert<2.2,>=2.0.3; sys_platform == "win32"
  Downloading pydivert-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 104.7/104.7 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting protobuf<3.15,>=3.14
  Downloading protobuf-3.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 173.5/173.5 kB 10.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting sortedcontainers<2.4,>=2.3
  Downloading sortedcontainers-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting zstandard<0.15,>=0.11
  Downloading zstandard-0.14.1.tar.gz (676 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 676.8/676.8 kB 14.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 63, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-suw_x1ii\zstandard\setup_zstd.py", line 164, in get_c_extension
          compiler.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 210, in msvc14_get_vc_env
          return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 164, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [25 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return hook(config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
        self.run_setup()
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 484, in run_setup
        super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
        exec(code, locals())
      File "<string>", line 63, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-suw_x1ii\zstandard\setup_zstd.py", line 164, in get_c_extension
        compiler.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 253, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 210, in msvc14_get_vc_env
        return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\DAS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dh4tf_vd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 164, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[INSTALL] Clean Up
=======================MobSF Clean Script for Windows=======================
Running this script will delete the Scan database, all files uploaded and generated.
C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\scripts
Deleting all uploads
Deleting all downloads
Deleting Static Analyzer migrations
Deleting Dynamic Analyzer migrations
Deleting MobSF migrations
Deleting temp and log files
Deleting Scan database
Deleting Secret file
Deleting Previous setup files
Deleting MobSF data directory: "C:\Users\DAS\.MobSF"
Done
[INSTALL] Migrating Database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF\manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Download and Install wkhtmltopdf for PDF Report Generation - https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html
[INSTALL] Installation Complete
[ERROR] Installation Failed!
Please ensure that all the requirements mentioned in documentation are installed before you run setup script.
Scroll up to see any installation errors.

The 'decorator==4.4.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application

C:\Users\DAS\Desktop\K\Pentesting Android\Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF>
```

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................